# Django: Local time representation with class-based views and crispy forms

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I am building an auction website with Django.  Potentially it could be used by users in differing time zones and so I have decided that all the underlying dates and times (such as datetime values in models) will be in UTC.

I'm using class-based views (ListView, DetailView, etc.) and crispy for displays.

What's the best strategy for conversion to local time on the page?  Should I do it in the view or in the template?

Comment: Convert on the template. You can try MomentJs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Ejaz.  I decided against Moment.js, but that gave me a push in the right direction - I hadn't thought of doing it with Javascript.  I added a function to my base template and then called it from the individual template

```
{# base.html #}

    <script>
        function utc2local_dt(utcDateTime) {
            const options = { year: 'numeric', month: 'short', day: 'numeric', hour: 'numeric', minute: '2-digit', hour12: false };
            var localDateTime = new Date(utcDateTime).toLocaleDateString('en-GB', options);
            return localDateTime;
        }
    </script>
```

```
{# myTemplate.html #}

    <td><a id="local-dt-auction-end" class="" href="#"></a></td>
    .
    .
    <script>
        document.getElementById("local-dt-auction-end").text = utc2local_dt('{{ listing.datetime_auction_end|date:"c" }}');
    </script>
{% endblock content %}
```